# Unable to locate the model you have specified - All i did was change servers

Tags: codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website, using the latest version of the frame work. I was hosting my website on Azure, and it was working fine - never any issues.

I've just moved all the files to a different server, a linux one - standard normal web hosting type server with cpanel.

My site loads up, however a lot of pages I use that require models, are giving off errors, as if the files do not exist

Unable to locate the model you have specified: UsersModel

**Just note : I have read so many articles today, that you need to have uppercase / lowercase and all that stuff, but that's how i already have it setup, it just does not work since changing servers. and it worked perfectly fine yesterday on the Azure server.**

Also, when going to the actual file in my address bar, it takes me to the 404 error. not sure if this has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your base url in config file ?
All model , controllers, helper ,library name must me capital letter.
If you change server remove index.php from config file where you will get config['index']= ""; and save this.

Still you get error then save  base url like domain/project_name/index.php

Comment: the base URL always remained the same, as the domain i pointed to the new server, and other pages that are not using models are loading perfectly fine :(

Comment: Change .htaccess file

Comment: change it to what?